# Cauchy's integral formula for real functions in real vector space

Tags: real-analysis

Cauchy's integral formula states that the value of a holomorphic scalar potential function within a disc in the complex plane is determined entirely by the values of the function on the boundary of the disc.

$f(a)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma f(z)\frac{1}{z-a}dz$

I am told that the same principle holds for real valued functions in real vector space with a real valued scalar potential field as long as you have zero divergence and zero curl within the disc. I would like to study these in order to develop a more intuitive understanding of why the math works the way it does.

Unfortunately I cant seem to find anything on the web about this. Maybe I am just googling the wrong thing.

Comment: What is your question? Be specific.

Comment: You might like to try googling for the mean value property of harmonic functions.

Comment: Thank you. I had heard of that but I didnt realize how important it was. From wikipedia: "all locally integrable functions satisfying the (volume) mean-value property are both infinitely differentiable and harmonic"

Comment: OK, its making more sense now. You use the Poisson kernel to form a weighted average of the boundary values. Thanks for the help. :-)